Paper GAMENet (2019): what is the intuition behind fusing two Graph Convolution Networks?
In paper GAMENet: Graph Augmented MEmory Networks for Recommending Medication Combination (Shang et al, 2019), the authors leveraged two graphs, where each node is a (unique) medication code. These two graphs have the same set of nodes, but are different in terms of edges between the nodes.

EHR Graph: an edge shows the two medications prescribed together at least once in EHR Data.
Drug-Drug Interaction Graph: an edge shows an undesired health effect when using these two medications together.

To create better representations for the nodes, such graphs are separately put through Graph Neural Network operation, as in Semi-Supervised Classification with Graph Convolutional Networks (Kipf et al, 2017).
What I don't understand is why afterward the author decides to fuse these two graphs ($Z_1$ and $Z_2$) in such a way $M_b = Z_1 - \beta Z_2$, to create a so-called Memory Bank ($M_b$)? Especially the minus sign. What is the intuition behind this technique?
                                                
For convenience, $M_b \in \mathbb{R}^{|C_m| \times d}$ where $C_m$ is the set of medication codes, and $d$ is an embedding dimension.
